# 2011 Moderator Election - Informal Q&A Thread

Tags: discussion, election

In connection with the moderator elections, we will be holding a Town Hall Chat session with the candidates.  This will be an opportunity for members of the community to pose questions to the candidates on the topic of moderation.  Participation is completely voluntary.  I am working with the candidates to find a time that allows the most participation.

(**Candidates**: candidates on other sites have reported that my email has been placed in their spam folder. Please be on the lookout for an email from me!)

Here are the details so far:

- I would like to schedule this towards the beginning of the election phase, so I am looking at the 14th-17th.  As soon as I coordinate with the existing moderators and candidates, I will edit this post with details on the "when".
- The Town Hall Chat will be a one-hour event using our [chat platform](http://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&sort=active&host=photo.stackexchange.com).
- The format will be an open discussion.  Users are encouraged to pose questions to the candidate regarding their thoughts on moderation.
- After the chat session, the transcript of the event will be permanently linked here.

Comment: Just a note...the 14th-17th is during my work week, and I'm usually unavailable from 8am through 6:30pm M-F (Mountain Time, GMT-7). The coming week we are ramping up a software release, so things get extra hectic. I am really only available on the weekends for chat stuff...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the small number of candidates and spread out availability, the community (via an [informal chat poll](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14/conversation/thc-scheduling)) has decided that rather than holding an actual Town Hall Chat, questions can informally be posed via meta or chat.

There will not be a formal Town Hall Chat for this election.

Answer (score 2):

OK... Well, I'll kick off the grilli...err... interroga... uhhh... *questions*. ;-)

**What do you envision the photo-SE community looking like one year from now, and how do you see yourself contributing to how the community will look via your role as moderator?**

Answer (score 2):

[*What do you envision the photo-SE community looking like one year from now, and how do you see yourself contributing to how the community will look via your role as moderator?*](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/764/2011-moderator-election-informal-qa-thread/774#774)

I think over the next year the community will probably be shifting a lot.  At our start, and for the first few months we had a **very** technical crowd, largely due to the link to stackoverflow. Lately, we are seeing a trend that I think will continue, which is that more and more creative type/professional photographers are contributing. As a moderator, the task at hand is to ensure that the community functions properly throughout the shift, and welcomes in new members that have a different (and very useful) viewpoint.